# How can one prepend text to each line of a multi-line variable?

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk, sed, variable

I print all the variables with there values

```
echo "$val"

 mapreduce.map.memory.mb,3584
 mapreduce.map.java.opts,-Xmx2560m
 mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb,3584
 mapreduce.reduce.java.opts,-Xmx2560m
 mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb,1280
```

how to append the word - type_config in the beginning of each line

so output will be as the following

```
 type_config,mapreduce.map.memory.mb,3584
 type_config,mapreduce.map.java.opts,-Xmx2560m
 type_config,mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb,3584
 type_config,mapreduce.reduce.java.opts,-Xmx2560m
 type_config,mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb,1280
```

Comment: That’s not a csv, that’s a variable with some newlines in it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ echo "$val" | sed 's/^/type_config,/g'
```

Output:

```
type_config,mapreduce.map.memory.mb,3584
type_config,mapreduce.map.java.opts,-Xmx2560m
type_config,mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb,3584
type_config,mapreduce.reduce.java.opts,-Xmx2560m
type_config,mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb,1280
```